# Could Java applet use other lib for web

Tags: java, security, jar, applet, digital-signature

This is web code for applet

```
<applet code=test.class name=test archive="thisDemo.jar">
</applet>
```

I write a class, and the class access the local data, so I use key to sign the applet.  But I need to use other library, like Apache jar.

How to use the the jar in applet?

I can use the Apache jar in eclipse, but can't work in applet when web call the applet.

Comment: Sign the library JAR(s), or use [tag:javawebstart].

Comment: *"the class access the local data."*  1) Local to what, the client or server? 2) What exactly happens when it "can't work"?  Copy/paste the error report. 3) Apache offers a lot of Jars, narrow it down. -- That HTML element is entirely invalid.  It pays to check these things with a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).  Then when you have it correct and understand it, use `deployJava.js to write the element that embeds the applet.

Comment: @trashgod  Barring use of the JNLP API, a JWS app. would also need to be signed.  Were you alluding to using the JNLP API services when you mentioned JWS?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Poor phrasing on my part; thank you for commenting. I had envisioned signing the auxiliary JAR for use with JWS, but I hadn't thought about using the JNLP API. I haven't tried [component extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#s213), but it looks like it might accommodate an already-sined JAR.

Comment: I know this is possible as I had done this before on a project of mine, however that was a long time ago so I don't remember what I did sorry

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<applet code=test.class name=test archive="thisDemo.jar,apache.jar" width="800" height="600">
</applet>
```

and putting `apache.jar` next to `thisDemo.jar`

You might need to sign every single dependency jar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229863/must-sign-all-jars-of-applet